# NPM 5 is not supported yet in React Native

Tags: node.js, npm

While creating an app using React native, in cmd I'm facing the following error message:

> ERROR: npm 5 is not supported yet.

`npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10`: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0

`> @expo/ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall C:\Users\Rakesh\proj\node_modules\@expo\ngrok > node ./postinstall.js  ngrok - binary unpacked.`

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file. `+ react-native-scripts@1.11.1 added 459 packages in 316.717s`.

It looks like you're using npm 5, which was recently released.  Create React Native App doesn't work with npm 5 yet, unfortunately. We recommend using npm 4 or yarn until some bugs are resolved.  You can follow the known issues with npm 5 at: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16991

Comment: Try to download and install latest version of node

Comment: should i download "latest version"? i downloaded recommended for most users. @jaydip

Comment: The error message pretty clearly says that react only works with npm 4, not npm 5 and it thinks you  have npm 5 installed.  It seems like you should remove any installed modules, uninstall npm 5, then install npm 4, then reinstall any modules you need.

Comment: how to install npm alone? can i have a link?

Answer (score 6):

You can downgrade your npm version by following

`npm install npm@4.6.1 -g`

and then try running app again.

Answer (score 2):

Simply downgrade **npm to 4.6.1** OR **Install Yarn**

```
npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

**OR**

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Yarn is better but I will prefer to **downgrade npm** because for some reason I'm getting a yarn.lock file error.